# Python xml.etree escaping

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

When using python's xml.etree module, how can I escape xml-special characters like '>' and '<' to be used inside a tag? Must I do so manually? Does etree have a method or kwarg that I am missing?

Consider:

```
In [1]: from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring

In [2]: root = Element('filter')

In [3]: root.set('type', 'test')

In [4]: for op in ['<', '>', '=']:
   ...:     sub_elem = SubElement(root, op)
   ...:     child = Element('a')
   ...:     child.text = 'b'
   ...:     sub_elem.append(child)
   ...:

In [5]: tostring(root)
Out[5]: '<filter type="test"><<><a>b</a></<><>><a>b</a></>><=><a>b</a></=></filter>'
```

Where I would like to see sections like:

```
<&lt><a>b</a></&lt>
```

Comment: why don't you use `for op in ['&lt;', '&gt;', '=']:` ?

Comment: `<&lt><a>b</a></&lt>` is very strange markup. Do you really want that? It is not well-formed XML, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where I would like to see sections like:
>
> `<&lt><a>b</a></&lt>`

This is not well-formed XML. I guess that you forgot the semicolons, but adding them does not help. The following is also ill-formed:

```
<&lt;><a>b</a></&lt;>
```

---

In the code, you are trying to create elements called `<`, `>`, and `=`. That won't work. All of the following are forbidden in XML element names: `<`, `>`, `=`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`.

Unfortunately, ElementTree is a bit lax and allows you to create pseudo-XML, such as this (from the question):

```
<filter type="test"><<><a>b</a></<><>><a>b</a></>><=><a>b</a></=></f‌​ilter>
```

If you had used `lxml.etree` (see http://lxml.de) instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you would have received an error message: "ValueError: Invalid tag name u'<'".

Answer (score 2):

`<` and `>` are [not valid characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) in XML, and should instead be replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

You can use a regular expression to replace the characters that are invalid:

```
import re

regexp = re.compile(r'<|>')  # here we are making a regex to catch either the character '<' or '>'
replacement_map = {'<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;'}  # a dict to map a character to the replacement value.
regexp.sub(lambda match: replacement_map[match.group(0)], '<a>hello</a>')  # do the replacement

# output: '&lt;a&gt;hello&lt;/a&gt;'
```

Though the code a a little more involoved, it is a very efficient way of doing the replacements.

Comment: this is a nice way to do replacements. my question revolved more around whether manual replacement was necessary. i was mostly confused why etree didn't escape for me, or at least expose an obvious option to allow said escaping.